# Container of 2 Types

Tags: c++, containers

Is there any C++ container that can store 2 (or more) types of values, such as ints and chars?  I want to make a blackjack game. The deck has to consist of both ints and chars. I don't want to initialize it with just numbers (so don't say anything about that!). I am a *very* beginner programmer, so don't make it too complicated.

Comment: Do you want to store an int and a char together, or just be able to add and remove either ints or chars to a container? If the former, just store a struct of int and char. If the latter, the only thing I know of is to store pointers and the type along with the pointer, because pointers are all one size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're a beginner, just use the basic stuff: a struct.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct{
  char cval;
  int ival;
};

int main(){
  using namespace std;

  vector<MyStruct> myvec;
  MyStruct values;

  values.cval = 'S';
  values.ival = 42;
  myvec.push_back(values);

  values.cval = 'A';
  values.ival = 1337;
  myvec.push_back(values);

  values.cval = 'X';
  values.ival = 314159;
  myvec.push_back(values);

  for(int i=0; i < myvec.size(); ++i)
    cout << "myvec[" << i << "], cval: " << myvec[i].cval << ", ival: " << myvec[i].ival << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
myvec[0], cval: S, ival: 42  
myvec[1], cval: A, ival: 1337  
myvec[2], cval: X, ival: 314159
```

You can see the output live [on Ideone](http://ideone.com/0SrJq).

Comment: +1, talk about Boost, Tuples and Pairs is great and all, but beginners need beginners' solutions.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that you need a container which is able to store either ints or chars.

First, take a look at the  `boost::any` datatype in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/any.html), that might help. You can then create a container of `boost::any` instances.

If you don't want to use `boost` or it seems overkill, use a `union` as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    char type;
    union {
        char character;
        int integer;
    };
} my_struct;
```

The contents of the `character` and the `integer` field in the union then occupy the same memory slots. (Well, the `integer` uses more slots since chars are usually only one byte). It is then up to you to set the `type` field of the struct to, say, `'c'` if you store a character and to, say, `'i'` to store an integer, and then access the contents of the struct using the `character` or the `integer` field depending on the value of `type`.

Finally, there's also the [QVariant](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qvariant.html) datatype of Qt, which works similarly to the second approach described above.

Comment: I need it to store ints and chars at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use all of the values simultaneously, you can use something like this...

```
std::pair<int,char> twovals;
std::pair<int,std::pair<char,float> > threevals;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a struct, class, or std::pair to group the different types into a composite type and then use the appropriate STL container.

Comment: like a class with data members of an int and a char?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boost Tuple objects.
More info : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html#using_library